# Local spectrum of a non-stationary gaussian process

Tags: gaussian-process

The [Wiener–Khinchin theorem](http://Wiener%E2%80%93Khinchin%20theorem) states that, for stationary processes, the covariance is the Fourier dual of the spectral density. I'm wondering if this statement is true for non-stationary processes if, say, the process only changes slowly. Within some range in which the process is *mostly* stationary, does the spectral density relate to the covariance?